# mouseUp firing after button click in mobile Safari (iOS simulator)

Tags: ios, backbone.js, coffeescript, trigger.io

I'm trying to build an editing view for a mobile app powered by Backbone.js and Trigger.io. The user goes to a note view and makes changes by tapping "edit" in the top right. When the "edit" button is tapped, we focus on the textarea containing the content and the "edit" button goes away and a "save" button appears. Whenever "edit" is tapped, however, a mouseUp event is firing which results in the textarea losing focus.

The mouseUp event does not fire if the edit button gets hidden and nothing replaces it. The mouseUp does fire if the edit button either A) remains or B) is hidden and save button replaces it.

The only way I've found to fix it is by setting a 200ms+ timeout between hiding the "edit" button and displaying the "save" button.

Is there something with mouseup events firing after click events and/or having them target separate elements? I'd post code but it's all over the place and would not provide much context. If you really need the code, I can post it in parts.

Comment: Can you try to do event.preventDefault() on the mouseUp event? If that doesn't help, it would make debugging much easier if you can reproduce it in a minimal example on jsfiddle or similiar.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Patrick. I tried preventDefault as well as stopPropagation. I can't reproduce on jsfiddle unfortunately as it only happens in the iOS simulator and I believe it has something to do with the timing of tap and touch events vs. click events (touchend is equivelant of mouseUp w/o delay due to lack of dbl tap events)

Comment: A bit of a longshot, but is your edit button implemented as a separate view? If so, it would be worth seeing if using [Backbone.View.remove](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) to clear up event handlers made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe iOs places a delay on the mouseup, to determine if a long touch is being performed.  This might help:

http://cubiq.org/remove-onclick-delay-on-webkit-for-iphone